# Background cmd Console window doesn't close automatically

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, console

I use below coding to open an application. The **PClist** has list of all IP address of the remote PCs that I want to execute the program and an dummy IP **0.0.0.0** at last to trigger the program execution at the master.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
st b="C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"
For %%B in (%b%) do (
    Set c=%%~dpB
    Set d=%%~nxB
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\COST\PCList.txt) do (
IF %%a equ 0.0.0.0 (
cd %c%
"%d%"
) ELSE (
ping %%a -n 1 -w 100
IF errorlevel 1 (
ECHO REMOTE %%a IS NOT REACHABLE
) else (
psexec \\%%a -i -d -s cmd /c cd %c%
psexec \\%%a -i -d -s cmd /c "%d%"
)
)
)
```

My problem is that when I run the above batch file the application opens and also an empty cmd console is open at background in the Master as well as slave PCs. It doesn't close until I close the launched application*(In this case Teamviewer)* or the directly the console window.

Is there any way to make the console window to close automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the answer. I changed the coding as below updated one and it works as I wanted it to. The trick was to use **`start`** as below syntax to run the application and close the console using **`exit`**.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
st b="C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"
For %%B in (%b%) do (
    Set c=%%~dpB
    Set d=%%~nxB
)
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (C:\COST\PCList.txt) do (
IF %%a equ 0.0.0.0 (
cmd /s /k "cd %c% && start "" "%d%" && exit"
) ELSE (
ping %%a -n 1 -w 100
IF errorlevel 1 (
ECHO REMOTE %%a IS NOT REACHABLE
) else (
psexec \\%%a -i -d -s cmd /s /k "cd %c% && start "" "%d%" && exit"
)
)
)
```